# Remove nested class in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to remove class's some of them are nested.

I know it is possible to remove a class like this:

```js
const coolDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div')
coolDiv.remove('container')
```

But how would I remove all `container` classes even the nested ones. For example how would I remove specific `class="container"` from the example below?

```js
<div class='my-div container'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='container'>
        DIV
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"how would I remove **all**"_ but then _"how would I remove **specific**"_ - Is it all or only a specific one?

Comment: If all: `document.querySelectorAll(".my-div .container, .my-div.container").forEach(({ classList }) => classList.remove("container"));`. The selector `.my-div .container, .my-div.container` scopes elements to descendants of `.my-div` or `.my-div` itself, having the `container` class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with `classList.remove`

```js
const coolDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div')
coolDiv.classList.remove('container')
```

```html
<div class='my-div container'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='container'>
        DIV
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList?retiredLocale=en)

---

Edit after see for multiple remove:

```js
const coolDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-div div')
coolDivs.forEach(coolDiv => {
  coolDiv.classList.remove('container')
});
```

```html
<div class='my-div container'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='container dontdeleteme'>
      <div class='red'>
        DIV
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I add two more case with others class.

Reference:

- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll?retiredLocale=en)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=en)